# Need to edit text file in Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Create a separate script that will edit the file and add the year in the contents.  How would I be able to do that

```
$content ="List of running Services"
$content | out-file C:\Windows\Temp\test
$textfile = get-content C:\Windows\Temp\test 
write-host $textfile
```

Comment: What trouble exactly?

Comment: I am trying to Create a separate script that will edit the file and add the year in the contents

Comment: you want to add the year but add to where? describe the issue clearly

Comment: Dates notwithstanding, adding content to an existing file, is a very common thing to do with examples all over the web and right here on SO. Just use the search box above.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments.

What you need is defined in the Powershell Help files.

Use the `Add-Content` cmdlet. Use the examples in the Powershell help files

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.1

```
# Example 1: Add a string to all text files with an exception
Add-Content -Path .\*.txt -Exclude help* -Value 'End of file'

# Example 2: Add a date to the end of the specified files
This example appends the date to files in the current directory and displays the date in the PowerShell console.

Add-Content -Path .\DateTimeFile1.log, .\DateTimeFile2.log -Value (Get-Date) -PassThru
```

The above examples show how to do things, add strings to a file as well as how to use the date. So, you can extrapolate them both, use Example 2 to get your date info and use example 1 to add the said date to the file contents.